# determine type of encoding/encryption

Tags: encryption, cryptography, encoding, cryptanalysis

Is there a way to find out what type of encryption is being used on this data? I was playing around with a game data and i cant get around it .
This Is the data im trying to decrypt, any help?
Code:
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

I cant figure out of its md5 salt or something else.